# Merge records or more into one in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Nieuws`
INNER JOIN `Nieuws_tags` ON `Nieuws_tags`.`ID-Nieuws` = `Nieuws`.`ID` 
INNER JOIN `Tags` ON `Tags`.`ID` = `Nieuws_tags`.`ID-tags` 
WHERE Nieuws.ID = 1
```

Right now my output is:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

So I need one record where the "Beschrijving" (tag) stack up and not give me 2 records.

Someone told me about GROUP_CONCAT but I don't really know how to insert that if necessary.

Comment: Either `MySQL` or `SQL` tag  please

Comment: <sql> and <mysql> combined is usually fine.

Comment: @jarlh not on SO, that was a hard lesson I've learned here :-)

Comment: I think it's answered here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv
It also depends a bit on the DBMS - some have specific commands to handle this

Comment: @ErikReder, that's an answer for SQL Server, that doesn't work with MySQL.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, SO wanted me to put more tags in so and I'm new to this. Thanks though.

Comment: @Thijs, I have answered 408 <mysql> questions. All of those questions have had the <sql> tag too.

Comment: @jarlh So it was okay for me to put the 2 tags?

Comment: It's perfectly fine. As long as a question is about the SQL language, you should also add a dbms tag!

Comment: I appreciate it @jarlh thank you.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? `only_full_group_by` may become an issue when upgrading to a more recent MySQL version.

Comment: Version 5.7.25 . Is that okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not 100% clear what is your DB schema, but just to show you the usage of `GROUP_CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT Nieuws.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Tags.Beschrijving)
FROM `Nieuws`
INNER JOIN `Nieuws_tags` 
ON `Nieuws_tags`.`ID-Nieuws` = `Nieuws`.`ID` 
INNER JOIN `Tags` 
ON `Tags`.`ID` = `Nieuws_tags`.`ID-tags` 
WHERE Nieuws.ID = 1
GROUP BY Nieuws.ID
```